# Error while connecting to wit api url using curl library in C code

Tags: c, http, post, curl, libcurl

Purpose : To get the response of the Wit API using curl library using C

Source code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  struct curl_slist *list = NULL;

  static const char *postthis="q=hello";

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.wit.ai/message);

    list = curl_slist_append(list, "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postthis);

/* if we don't provide POSTFIELDSIZE, libcurl will strlen() by
   itself */ 
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long)strlen(postthis));

/* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
/* Check for errors */ 
  if(res != CURLE_OK)
   fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
          curl_easy_strerror(res));

/* always cleanup */ 
   curl_slist_free_all(list);
   curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
return 0;
}
```

$TOKEN is the authentication token of Wit Api

Error: Bad auth, check token/params

Comment: Is `$TOKEN` supposed to be a shell environment variable, or just a placeholder in the code you show? Also, when posting code and it's not about build errors, then please make sure it compiles as otherwise those other errors could distract from your actual question (that's part of the "Verifiable" meaning in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: Hello Jachim, Thanks for the reply ,$TOKEN is a number not a shell env variable, i'm passing this number from my Wit API and i'm not getting compilation errors but a runtime error.

Comment: It's not clear where `$TOKEN` comes from, is it passed to the http headers verbatim, i.e. as `$TOKEN`?

Comment: The wit api generates the token no I paste it in the code there in the place of $TOKEN.

Comment: I get this error too, but stochastically. I've done the exact same curl request twice; once where I get this error, once where it works. I suspect it could be the wrong error message for a timeout issue.